# What is the hexagon funnel shaped thing that came with my aeropress for?

Tags: aeropress, identify-this

When I bought my aeropress, it came with this weird hexagon thingy: [image: hexagon thingy]

What is it for?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It took me an embarrassingly long time to realize the purpose of this hexagon shaped funnel, so I am sharing this via a self posted answer.

The hexagon funnel has three purposes:

1. It is a funnel to make it easier to pour your ground coffee into the aeropress opening. [image: funnel for putting ground coffee into aeropress]
2. It is a funnel for cups with a small opening at the top. The image shows a shot-glass as an example. Trying to use an aeropress with a cup that is too small sucks. [image: as a funnel for small cups]
3. It is a stand, so when your aeropress is stowed, it all neatly stacks together. [image: stacked aeropress]

Comment: I didn't know about #3! Looks like it would also come in handy when using the inverted method... It really is a nicely engineered kit, innit :-)

Comment: The backstory is rather interesting. The inventor is the same guy that brought us the Aerobie frisbies/flying disks. See http://priceonomics.com/the-invention-of-the-aeropress/ for a nice write up.

Comment: Yeah, I'd seen that! Part of why I bought one in the first place...

Comment: The third picture shows it with the rubber seal on the end of the plunger half-way down the tube.  That compresses the seal which the manufacturer says reduces its lifespan.  For that reason, seems better to store it the other way up, with the filter cover unscrewed and removed.  Push the plunger all the way in so the seal comes out the end.  Stand the tube on the base that holds the filter papers.  Put the funnel in the top and stack the stirrer, filter cover and scoop in the funnel.

Comment: @CroadLangshan thanks for the feedback, I updated the third photo based on your comment.

Comment: This is genius! I knew there had to be a simple way for all the components to link together.